# Preposition after "Credited"

Tags: prepositions

Which is grammatically correct between to and as? If both are available, which is more natural?

Ex1) You made a serious blunder in the CD booklet! The track1 composer is mistakenly credited as/to Mr. Ken. It should be Mr. Kann!

Ex2) The singer is credited as/to her nickname for the song because she doesn't want her real name to be revealed in public.

Comment: What research have you done to try to answer this question yourself. What online dictionaries with examples have you consulted? Have you searched the web with alternatives?

Comment: The preposition could be *to*, *by*, *for*, *as*, *with*, and probably a dozen others.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between "credited to" and "credited as". *Credited to* emphasizes the person who is being given the credit. *Credited as* emphasizes the name that is receiving the credit, so it often is used for pseudonyms or when the wrong person is mistakenly given the credit. For example, from the Web:

> John Lennon, credited as Dr. Winston O'Boogie, played guitar on this recording.

So for your first example, I think both *as* and *to* work (assuming Mr. Ken is a real person and not just a typo), but in your second example, the preposition should be *as*.

Answer (score 0):

The correct preposition depends on the SUBJECT. The two choices are...

> ***Track 1** is mistakenly credited **to** Mr Ken.*
> ***The track 1 composer** is mistakenly credited **as** Mr Ken.*

But in practice I suggest most people would use a different verb (e.g. - ***listed, given,...***) for the second usage. ***Unless*** it was a *very* contrived context where "Mr Ken" was in fact an alternative "stage name" used by Mr Kann (for some of his *other* work, but *not this CD*).

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios that one may be trying to express by the formulations that are at stake here.

**Scenario 1**

There are **two** different composers: Ken and Kann. The actual composer was Kann, but the booklet mistakenly states that it was Ken. That can be expressed by saying that the track was mistakenly credited **to** Ken. The preposition tells us that the mistake concerns where the credit went: it went to the wrong person. Note, however, that even in that scenario we would not say that the 'composer is mistakenly credited to Mr. Ken'.

**Scenario 2**

There is only **one** composer that is relevant, but there is some confusion about whether his name is spelled as *Ken* or *Kann*. The correct spelling is *Kann*, but the people who wrote the booklet mistakenly thought that it was *Ken*. That can be expressed by saying that the composer was mistakenly credited **as** Ken. In this scenario, unlike the first one, the credit went to the right person; the preposition *as* tells us that the mistake concerns the manner of giving the credit to that person.

It should be noted that 'the composer was mistakenly credited as Ken' means something different from 'Ken was mistakenly credited as the composer'; the latter formulation would fit Scenario 1.

Answer (score -1):

Both are wrong. With contortions of gymnastic proportions, you can might make an acceptable sentence out of your given sentences. Better to use the idiomatically used phrase "**give credit**"(FARLEX link: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+credit). Then your sentences could be constructed as

> Mr. Ken is mistakenly **given credit as** the track1 composer.
>
> The singer's nickname is **given credit**
>
> or
>
> The singer's nickname **is being given** credit

The juggling of the phrases is necessary as without that they would sound weird.

Comment: IMO, these are worse than the original. "is credited" is much better than "is being given credit".

Comment: @StuartF: Yes, and putting "Mr. Ken" as the subject only works if Mr. Ken is a real, separate person from Mr. Kann, rather than (as is possible, even likely, in the example) a misspelling/typo.